# Uploading filepaths to a database

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to upload two files from one input, both files appear in the uploads folder as they should but only one filepath goes into the database.

E.g. if I upload test1.pdf and test2.pdf they will both go into the uploads folder but test1.pdf will be inserted in both columns of the database instead of just one.

Can anyone help me please before I go insane?

```
 if (count($_FILES['field2']['name']) >= 1) {


    //Loop through each file
    for ($i = 0; $i < count($_FILES['field2']['name']); $i++) {
        //Get the temp file path
        $tmpFilePath = $_FILES['field2']['tmp_name'][$i];

        //Make sure we have a filepath
        if ($tmpFilePath != "") {

            //save the filename
            $shortname = $_FILES['field2']['name'][$i];

            //save the url and the file
            $filePath = "uploads/" . date('d-m-Y-H-i-s') . '-' . $_FILES['field2']['name'][$i];
            $filePath1 = "uploads/" . date('d-m-Y-H-i-s') . '-' . $_FILES['field2']['name'][$i];

            //Upload the file into the temp dir
            if (move_uploaded_file($tmpFilePath, $filePath)) {


     $sql = "INSERT INTO " . $config_tbl_prefix . " subcontractor_qs         (field1, field2)

     VALUES
     ('$filePath','$filePath1')";

     mysql_query($sql);

        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Why you are using mysql* function it's deprecated in newer version in php and removed in PHP7.

Comment: You need a loop.

Comment: @RossH why are you even developing if you don't care?

Comment: @Script47 - Can you show me how please?

Comment: you just upload filepath so in this case it will upload one file

 if (move_uploaded_file($tmpFilePath, $filePath)) {

Comment: @ShafiqulIslam Can you tell me how I upload both please?

Answer (score 0):

```
if (count($_FILES) >= 1) {


//Loop through each file
foreach ($_FILES as $id=>$file) {
    //Get the temp file path
    $tmpFilePath = $file['tmp_name'];

    //Make sure we have a filepath
    if ($tmpFilePath != "") {

        //save the filename
        $shortname = $file['name'];

        //save the url and the file
        $filePath = "uploads/" . date('d-m-Y-H-i-s') . '-' . $file['name'];

        //Upload the file into the temp dir
        if (move_uploaded_file($tmpFilePath, $filePath)) {


        $sql = "INSERT INTO " . $config_tbl_prefix . " subcontractor_qs (field1) VALUES ('$filePath')";

        mysql_query($sql);

         }
       }
     }
   }
 }
```

Comment: Won't that only upload one file though, that's the same problem I have now. I need to upload more than one at a time.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to upload two or more file using same input filed then update your code . in this code save file name and path . at a time you can not get both file path using loop.

**1. important thing remove mysql and use pdo or mysqli**

```
 <if (count($_FILES['enviroupload']['name']) >= 1) {
//Loop through each file
for ($i = 0; $i < count($_FILES['enviroupload']['name']); $i++) {
    //Get the temp file path
    $tmpFilePath = $_FILES['enviroupload']['tmp_name'][$i];

    //Make sure we have a filepath
    if ($tmpFilePath != "") {

        //save the filename
        $shortname = $_FILES['enviroupload']['name'][$i];

        //save the url and the file
        $filePath = "uploads/" . date('d-m-Y-H-i-s') . '-' . $_FILES['enviroupload']['name'][$i];

        //Upload the file into the temp dir
        if (move_uploaded_file($tmpFilePath, $filePath)) {

            $sql = "INSERT INTO " . $config_tbl_prefix . " subcontractor_qs         (field1, field2)

 VALUES
 ('$shortname','$filePath')";

            //mysql_query($sql);
            echo $sql;
            echo "<br>";

        }
    }
}
```

}

in this code file path and file name will save in db , if you want to only save file path then need update your code

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion or debugging sessions, and we discourage users from taking interactions off this website. Additional information should be edited into the question or the answer.